# PowerMock a static method inside another static method

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito, powermock

I have the following code

```
    import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
 
public class DatabaseReader {
 
    public static final String CONNECTION = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/testdb";
     
    public static String getById(Integer id) throws SQLException {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM Foo WHERE Id = ?";
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(CONNECTION);
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        preparedStatement.setInt(1, id);
        ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
         
        resultSet.next();
         
        String result = resultSet.getString(0);
         
        resultSet.close();
        preparedStatement.close();
        connection.close();
         
        return result;
    }
    
    public static String getId(int id) throws SQLException{
        return getById(id); 
    }
}
```

Is it possible to powermock the function getById so that when I test getId, I get a mocked value for getById?
I was trying this:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.fail;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mockStatic;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.verifyStatic;
 
import java.sql.SQLException;
 
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;
    
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
    @PrepareForTest(DatabaseReader.class)
    public class DatabaseReaderTest {
     
        @Test
        public void testGetById() {
            int inputId = 1;
            String returnValue = "JavaCodeGeeks";
     
            mockStatic(DatabaseReader.class);
     
            try {
                when(DatabaseReader.getById(inputId))
                    .thenReturn(returnValue);
                String actual = DatabaseReader.getId(inputId);
                System.out.println(actual);
                verifyStatic();
                assertEquals(returnValue, actual);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                fail("No exception should be thrown.");
            }
        }
```

But, it is not working when I call

```
String actual = DatabaseReader.getId(inputId);
```

it tries to call the whole database method.
I am confused about whether IU can mock a static method call from a static method.

Comment: getId is such a trivial method that I wouldn't bother testing it. On the other hand it would be good to have a test to check that getById doesn't leak a connection if executeQuery throws an exception.

Comment: I wanted to understand if, at all, we can test a static method called from inside another static method using powermock api.

Comment: Please add your imports to your test code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should test like this.

Object **under test** can never be your mock (PreparedForTest in terms of PowerMock), you're supposed to test the real code, not "power-mock enhanced" something that might or might not behave like a real code.

Mocks (even those managed by Power mock) are meant to mimic the behavior of "dependencies".

Now every code is unit testable, so sometimes if you want it to be tested properly you should modify it: use dependency injection (which is basically not compatible with make-everything-static) approach, in general use about the better dependencies separation and so forth.

In general Power Mock is a tool that we should never use (ok this might be subjective but besides my own opinion I've heard this statement from variety of different resources) unless we're talking about some legacy systems maybe.

So Bottom line, general suggestion is: get rid of static methods and refactor. If this if for education purposes and you really want to learn PowerMock:

Don't "touch" `DatabaseReader` class (read, don't enhance it/change its bytecode with power mock)

Instead, mock the `DriverManager` (PowerMock), `Connection` (Mockito/EasyMock/whatever), `PreparedStatement`(Mockito/EasyMock/whatever) and `ResultSet` (Mockito/EasyMock/whatever)

Answer (score 0):

You're using the mockito `when`. You need to use the `org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.when`.